# SQL - Joining tables BUT not always

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I need to perform a query SELECT that joins three tables (no problem with that). Nonetheless, the third table can, or NOT, have any element that match the joining KEY.

I want ALL data from the first two tables and if the ITEMS have ALSO information in the third table, fetch this data to.

For example, imagine that the first table have a person, the second table have his/her address (everyone lives anywhere), the third table stores the driving license (not everyone has this) - but I need to fetch all data whether or not people (all people) have driving license.

Thanks a lot for reading, if possible to give you suggestion / solution!

Comment: use `LEFT JOIN` against the third table instead of `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` to join the third table. Using `INNER JOIN` a row has to exists. Using `LEFT JOIN`, the 'gaps' will be filled with `NULL`s.

```
SELECT
  p.PersonID, -- NOT NULL
  -- dl.PersonID, -- Can be null. Don't use this one.
  p.FirstName,
  p.LastName,
  a.City,
  a.Street,
  dl.ValidUntilDate
FROM
  Person p
  INNER JOIN Addresse a ON a.AddressID = p.HomeAddressID
  LEFT JOIN DrivingLicence dl ON dl.PersonId = p.PersonID
```

Comment: Terrific
Thank you very much

Comment: I've noticed that when the third table doesn't have data (person doesn't have driving license) I CAN'T use (fetch assoc array) personID. 
I mean (for example) $result['personID'] is NULL.
Only for people who have d.l. I can grab this value ->  $result['personID']

Comment: `dl.PersonID` is null if there is no matching record in `dl`. To get the right id, use `p.PersonID`, because that one will always exist.

Comment: If the third table doesn´t have data for one person the $result['personID'] is null, otherwise is NOT null. But personID is NOT null in the first two tables... I should be able to use it because it was the joining key. Am I wrong? Thanks

Comment: It depends on which table you get the PersonID from. If you use `dl.PersonID` in your query, you will get NULL for people who don't have a d.l. If you use `p.PersonID` in your query you'll be fine. Make sure you use the right table alias for the field. I've also added this in the query in the answer.

Comment: I will show my code. I'd appreciate if you could take a look please:        SELECT p.products_model, p.products_id, p.products_quantity, p.products_status, p.products_weight, p.products_price, p.manufacturers_id, pd.products_name, pd.language_id, ptc.categories_id, s.products_id, s.specials_new_products_price 
    
    FROM products p 
    INNER JOIN products_to_categories ptc  ON ptc.products_id = p.products_id
    INNER JOIN products_description pd ON pd.products_id = ptc.products_id
    LEFT JOIN specials s ON s.products_id = pd.products_id

Comment: Like I said, `s.products_id` should be `pd.products_id` in the `SELECT` list of fields. `s.products_id` can be NULL, but `pd.products_id` will be okay. You could also use `ptc.products_id` or `p.products_id`, since they are all the same id, only the one in `s` is LEFT JOINED, and can therefor be null.

Comment: Would you please be so kind as to read and interpret my answers? You just have to change 1 letter, but I really cannot explain which one it is more clearly than I've done already.